# Spring roo is not working

Tags: spring-roo

I am currently working on windows 7, 64 bits. I installed a clean version of sts 2.7.2 with spring roo and at first everything was working flawlesly. Later, I tried to install the standalone version of spring roo 1.1.5. As soon as I typed roo I started getting the following stack trace:

`[org.springframework.roo.felix [44]] [org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl] The activate method has thrown an exc
eption
org.apache.felix.log.LogException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: unknown object in stream: 7
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.getTrustedKeys(PgpServiceImpl.java:152)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.trust(PgpServiceImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.trustDefaultKeys(PgpServiceImpl.java:110)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.trustDefaultKeysIfRequired(PgpServiceImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.activate(PgpServiceImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:227)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:38)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:591)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:472)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:146)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createImplementationObject(ImmediateComponentManager.java:
226)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createComponent(ImmediateComponentManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DelayedComponentManager.createRealComponent(DelayedComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Registered.getService(AbstractComponentManager.java:1148)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DelayedComponentManager.getService(DelayedComponentManager.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.getService(Felix.java:3139)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:411)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.getService(DependencyManager.java:785)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$1.getInstance(DependencyManager.java:1039)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BindMethod.getParameters(BindMethod.java:564)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:226)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:38)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:591)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$NotResolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:548)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:472)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.invokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1028)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.bind(DependencyManager.java:944)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.open(DependencyManager.java:868)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createImplementationObject(ImmediateComponentManager.java:
200)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createComponent(ImmediateComponentManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfied.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:997)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:333)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.serviceAdded(DependencyManager.java:283)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.serviceChanged(DependencyManager.java:170)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:871)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:733)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:662)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:3890)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.access$000(Felix.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$2.serviceChanged(Felix.java:728)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:107)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:2979)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:449)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerComponentService(AbstractComponentManager.java:460)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfied.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:1009)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:333)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.serviceAdded(DependencyManager.java:283)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.serviceChanged(DependencyManager.java:170)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:871)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:733)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:662)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:3890)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.access$000(Felix.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$2.serviceChanged(Felix.java:728)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:107)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:2979)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:449)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerComponentService(AbstractComponentManager.java:460)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfied.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:1009)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:333)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:157)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfiguredComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfiguredComponentHolder.java:256)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.loadDescriptor(BundleComponentActivator.java:253)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:147)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:111)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:285)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.bundleChanged(Activator.java:203)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3879)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1850)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unknown object in stream: 7
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory.nextObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.pgp.PgpServiceImpl.getTrustedKeys(PgpServiceImpl.java:142)
    ... 83 more`

I tried to search for this but couldn't find anything, so I install the 1.2.0M1 version however I got the same problem. After a while, I gave up and tried to keep working with the roo shell that lives within the ide that was working before. Nevertheless, my ide didn't seem to work anymore. When I try to execute any command on an existing roo project or try to create a new project just hangs forever. 
In order to fix it, I tried to delete sts, install it again, restart my pc, clean the registry, install a different version like 1.7.1, change my jdk from 1.6_22 to 1.6_27 but I always got the same issue now.

I have read quite a lot on spring roo and was really looking forwards to starting using it however I run out of ideas.

Is there anything I can do to get it working again?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I run both the eclipse and the command line at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, I was hit by [STS-1931](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1931). Removing the ~/.spring_roo_pgp.bpg cleared the problem.

Comment: I had to delete some other cache and STS related files inside the ROO root directory to make it work again. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: what is the location of spring_roo_pgp.bpg file in spring roo?